# DataContract for type is already present and the contracts are not equivalent

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm getting the following error when browsing my wcf service in IE:

```
DataContract for type PredefinedNote cannot be added to DataContractSet since type [IEnumerable[PredefinedNote]] with the same data contract name 'serviceResponseBaseGeneric' in namespace 'http://test.service.schema' is already present and the contracts are not equivalent
```

Here is the Service Contract in question:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://test.service.schema")]
public interface IPredefinedNotesService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<PredefinedNote> GetPredefinedNotes(NoteKindIdentifier noteKind);

    [OperationContract]
    PredefinedNote GetPredefinedNoteById(int id);
}
```

Oddly enough I can successfully make calls to the web service and get the expected results, but get this error when browsing the service in IE.

Comment: It sounds like you have another service registered that uses that PredefinedNote class. Search your solution for PredefinedNote and make sure it is not defined twice.

Comment: I just checked and it's the only service that uses the PredefinedNote class.